# Java dynamic class cast

Tags: java, dynamic, casting

I'm aware that this could be a possible duplicate, but the other threads haven't solved my problem completely.

Let's say I have the following classes A and B which extend BasicClass.

```
public abstract class BasicClass {
   // ...
}

public class A extends BasicClass {
   // ...
}

public class B extends BasicClass {
   // ...
}
```

And now I want to cast class A to B dynamically.

```
a.getClass().cast(bClass.newInstance);
```

but every time I get an Exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
```

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

Because A is not extending B. (technicaly:  A IS not B)

### Explanation:

JVM performs "IS-A" test before it casts.
If "IS-A" test fails, you will get "ClassCastException".(Just like you are getting now).

IS-A :
IS-A test is to check whether a class(to be casted, in your case A) is in inheritance tree of the class(casted to, in your case B).

IS-A is the functional term, syntax to check IS-A test is instanceof".
e.g a instanceof b : 
explanation of instance of:
LHS and RHS of the instance of must be the object.
thus a and b are obeject.
Their respective classes are checked for inheritance.

### In your example following result will come.

a instanceof b : False

a instanceof basicObject : True

b instanceof  a : False

b instanceof  basicObject : True

basicObject instanceof a : False

basicObject instanceof b : False

You can only cast where result of instanceof is true.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got it now. Would it be possible to cast A to B in two steps: A -> BasicClass -> B ?

Comment: @user2948795 A cast does not change the type of the object. Nothing can do that. Casting lets you view a reference of one type as a reference of another type.

Answer (score 4):

Because, in your inheritance hierarchy, a `B` is not an `A`. You cannot cast one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy looks like this:

```
   BasicClass
      / \
     /   \
    A     B
```

`A` is not an ancestor of `B`, so it's impossible to cast an instance of `B` to `A`.